# I have a response coming from the server( JSON Response) Those contain image names

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Stack overflow people, I have a data coming from the server those are the images i just want to display them under my card view of an application. Kindly help me out in displaying those response

Here is my code

**HOME.Ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, LoadingController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {HttpProvider} from '../../providers/http-provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers:[HttpProvider]
})
export class HomePage {

    newsData: any;
    loading: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private httpProvider:HttpProvider,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController)
  {
     this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: `
  <ion-spinner ></ion-spinner>`
});

    this.getdata();
  }

getdata(){
  this.httpProvider.getJsonData().subscribe(
    result => {
      this.newsData=result.data.image;
      console.log("Success : "+this.newsData);
      alert("Data coming");
    },
    err =>{
      console.error("Error : "+err);
    } ,
    () => {
      console.log('getData completed');
    }
  );
}



}
```

**HOME.HTML**

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title>
World News
</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-card text-wrap *ngFor="let item of newsData">

  <ion-card-content padding>

    <p>
       {{item.image}}
    </p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

**HTTP Provider.TS**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class HttpProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello HttpProvider Provider');
  }

  getJsonData(){
  return this.http.get('stay-simple.co.nf/display.php').map(res => res.json());
}

}
```

Database table fields 
id, Image, text

JSON Response link:http://stay-simple.co.nf/display.php

Kindly help me out of this Project work

Comment: check your link.. you seem to have some server side issues... Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what is the format of an image? base64 or what? Are you getting response from the server?

Comment: I have just used json_encode($row["image"]) of image field of database.

Comment: Yes the response is coming in the form of JSON format

Comment: Link:  http://stay-simple.co.nf/display.php

Comment: Yes i made it as base 64 image response now